# Google Collab keeps on crashing because it runs out of memory

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory, kaggle, resnet

I'm trying to build a Resnet200D transfer learning model for a kaggle competition but I'm unable to train the model on Google Collab since it runs out of memory even with a batchSize of 1 on CPU as well as GPU. I'm not sure where the memory is getting used up since other participants claim they've been able to train the model with a batch size of 16 as well. If anyone could look at the notebook and leave suggestions, that would be really helpful.
[Google Collab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hPMpAH-n0JlN9fbrq2apb-Zi3_U-Xh1c?usp=sharing)

Comment: Kindly post the memory being used up error from the google collab to view.

Comment: This is error that I'm getting "Your session crashed after using all available RAM. If you are interested in access to high-RAM runtimes, you may want to check out"

Comment: It should not happen unless you have modifications done on your code. The memory being used up could be a sign of the actual model compiling process eating up all the resources or the actual data set being loaded into the disk. Anyways, you could use a trick to double up the RAM on your notebook, might or might not work though: https://towardsdatascience.com/upgrade-your-memory-on-google-colab-for-free-1b8b18e8791d

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, it did not work. Would it be possible for you to look the the notebook I've shared and see if i'm making some other mistake which could be causing this/

Comment: I tried your notebook and it crashes at the second code cell itself. The appending function is in infinite loop. Are you sure that is what you are trying to achieve? Recheck your code flow again. It should work.

Comment: The appending function was suggested in the link you shared in order to double up the RAM on the notebook. I was just testing that.. The code crashes without that line as well. Although, you won't be able to run the notebook without uploading a kaggle.json file at line 4 (files.upload())